# gtk treeview cell renderer text -- changed signal

Tags: treeview, gtk, signals, cellrenderer

I am using the followed to renderer text in cells:

```
  renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
  column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes((local = char_to_utf8 ("weight(kg/m)")), renderer, "text", MEM_SEC_WEIGHT_PER_METER, NULL);
  g_free(local);
  gtk_tree_view_append_column(treeview, column);
```

I **don't** set `editable` attribute for the renderer. The value for specified cell is set by other sub-function. Then how can I get the `changed` signal for the specified cell when its value is changed? My purpose is to update other widget when text value in cell is changed. For the text cell renderer, it only has `edited` signal that is not useful for my case (or maybe I misunderstand some points).

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cellrenderers.html#cellrenderertext

If a cell is edited, an "edited" signal is emited. You need to connect this signal to your own edit-function, which saves the edited result to that liststore/treestore.

Comment: As I said, the cell is not editable. Its value is set by other function. There is no `edited' signal connecting with the cell.

Comment: Well, in that case, you can bind function to 'row-changed' signal of GtkListStore/GtkTreeStore.